# SQL Sever 2008 R2 Installation error: Unsupported 16-bit Application

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, 64-bit

Running Windows Web Server 2008 R2 and I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard from MSDNAA (includes install package for x86, x64, and ia64).

I receive the following error while trying to run the setup.exe

```
"Unsupported 16-bit Application"
```

> "The program or feature "\??\E:\SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard(x86, x64, ia64) - DVD (English)\x64\setup100.exe" cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit windows compatible version is available"

Windows Server 2008 is running on an AMD X2 4400+ and installed as 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, kill the file, clear download caches, download again. Point.

Happens when you get bad images.