# Unsupported 16-Bit application & unexpected return code 216

Tags: windows-server-2012, deployment, wds, mdt

So i finally made it to install couple of applications, while i still need programs out developers use a lot: PHPStorm, Putty, WinSCP, GITBash and Xshell5.

and from every program i get this error message:
**Unsupported 16-Bit application**
The program or feature
"\??\C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\WINscp\WinSCP-5.9.2-Setup.exe" cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available

this is with every one of these programs.

What i am using is Windows 2008 R2 with hyper-V and on an virtual server i have Windows server 2012 R2 running with WDS and MDT 2013 Update 2 with ADK for Windows 10 1607. my client is an Dell Vostro V130 for testing, this laptop is going to have Win10 Pro x64 installed on it

and i do not get it because when i try to install in normally on the client it works just fine, i did search on the site and this is what came close to my own [problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/223886/sql-sever-2008-r2-installation-error-unsupported-16-bit-application) and i tried that it did not work.

i changed the installation type by checking the middle one when u try to add a new application application without source files or elsewhere on the network and even that did not change the outcome, and the only error i get at the end of my deployment is this: **Application X returned an unexpected return code: 216** for me it is unclear and i can't get a clear asnwer to my question hopefully you guys do.

i am struggling with this problem for 2 days now and i can not see what the problem is and it is very tempting to rip my own hair out.

Thanks in advance,
Stef

Comment: (Stef), Were we able to resolve the issues earlier? If so then I can write the answer that we discovered. Thanks!

Comment: yes, you can write the answer we discovered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Application Compatibility Layer

The 64bit version of Microsoft Windows does not include a translation layer to handle 16 bit applications.

To use 16 bit programs, you will need a copy of 32bit Windows. As the 32bit version has a 16 bit layer.

However in this specific case we discovered that the file itself was corrupted. To correct the corruption we obtained a new copy of the application and it worked properly.

---

## How to check your files for corruption:

Use a hash checker to check your file's hash against an official hash posted on your software author's website.

I personally recommend quick hash:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/quickhash/

It is multi platform, free, supports multiple hashing algorithms and it has multiple hashing modes.